# CertUtil silent mode. Unable to install Certificate silently

Tags: certificate, windows-server-2008, citrix

Does anyone know how could I installed the following silently ?

```
C:\> certutil -importpfx -user -f -p [Password] "O:\Certificates\test2.pfx"
```

I tried using the `-silent` option but it says it does not exist.

Any other recommendations ?

The certificate install is causing issues with our users, since they are unable to say yes to install it. A Citrix security box appears behind the certificate window which needs to be 'allowed' before they can install the certificate. Some users are able to drag the security warning from the back to the front, but the majority are unable to do so.

If anyone could help that would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, if you could silently install user certificates it would be a hefty security breach.

Comment: If we try to install in the system (i.e. without `-user` option), the operation is performed silently. Why is a security breach to install in the user store, but it is not if we install in the system store (of course, running both commands as administrator)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a vbs script such as below to call your bat file during logon, this will install silently..

VBS SCRIPT

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") Dim strArgs strArgs = "cmd /c %LOGONSERVER%\netlogon\import-certificate.bat" oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

BATCH SCRIPT

```
certutil -f -user -p "PASSWORD" -importpfx "%LOGONSERVER%\netlogon\CERTIFICATE.pfx" NoRoot
```